# How to show subcategories using loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop, categories

i am using `wp_list_categories('child_of=54&title_li=')` method to display all the subcategories, but it is showing only one, how can i use it with loop to show all the subcategories properly.

Comment: That works for me. Do the missing subcategories have posts? By default the categories without posts are hidden, but you can add `&hide_empty=0` to change that.

Comment: yes i have added the posts, actually i want to display the subcategories using loop.

Comment: i am giving solution of my own question, `<?php $descendant=array('child_of'=>54)?> <?php $categories = get_categories($descendant);?> <?php foreach($categories as $category) :?> <?php echo $category->name;?> <?php endforeach;?>`

Comment: @PieterGoosen, if my answer is correct, you can vote it too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am giving solution of my own problem :)

```
<?php 
$descendant= array('child_of'=>54);
$categories = get_categories($descendant);
foreach($categories as $category) :
    echo $category->name;
endforeach;
?>
```